# eBay API - How to get number of active listings in each country?

Tags: ebay-api

Is there any way to use the eBay API to get the number of active listings in each country/eBay site?

I have 80,000+ listings split across 7 different ebay sites. I cannot use the Trading API as this is limited to 25,000 results.

I have looked at the Merchant Data API and the ActiveInventoryReport call. It has a SiteFilter but the Api Reference just says "Reserved for internal or future use." I tested it and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I got a semi-official answer from eBay. It's not possible:

> Right now we dont have a way to get the listings per site basis. You
>   will have to add extra logic in your application to check the Listing
>   Site of the Item.